# What is it called: a box of 24 beer cans or a package of 24 beer cans?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Look at this picture

[image]

There is a box and there are 24 cans of beer in the box.

What is it called: **a box / package of 24 beer cans** or **a box / a package of 24 cans of beer**?

Comment: You don't need to start questions of this type with the words "Look at this picture".

Comment: In what part of the world are you, and do you want an industrial term, slang, or something else? In Ontario, for example, what you have is a *two-four*. In most of the U.S. it would be a *case*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all of those would do.

Do you need to mention the cardboard container?

> I bought my mate 24 cans of beer for his birthday.

It might be more natural not to say whether they were in a box or not.

"24 beer cans" could be empty cans. But in context, nobody would be confused.

Comment: A package or box of bottles or cans of an alcoholic beverage is sometimes called a 'case', usually of a set number like 6, 12, 24, etc. This term i s common on grocery websites and wine shop lists.